# Database structure for storing historical data and reporting on data annually

Tags: oracle, database-design

I am using an Oracle database. I have a system of let’s say strings. Not like in datatype string but string like in small pieces of rope.

A string start and end can change over the years. A history must be kept of these changes. Reporting are done annually. The user wants to see what the start and end of the string was in 2016, 2017, 2018 etc.
A string can change a couple of times a year or only once in 2/3 years. The user is just interested in the latest changes for a specific year. What was the valid start and end for the year 2016 or 2017 etc?

```
CREATE TABLE STRINGLIST
(
  ID            NUMBER,
  STRINGID      NUMBER,
  STRING        VARCHAR2(7 BYTE),
  STRING_START  NUMBER,
  STRING_END    NUMBER,
  CREATE_DATE   DATE,
  CREATED_BY    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  EXPIRE_DATE   DATE,
  EXPIRED_BY    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
)

Insert into PMS2020.STRINGLIST
   (ID, STRINGID, STRING, STRING_START, STRING_END, 
    CREATE_DATE, CREATED_BY, EXPIRE_DATE, EXPIRED_BY)
 Values
   (1, 1, 'string1', 0, 5, 
    TO_DATE('02/02/2015 12:31:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'user1', TO_DATE('04/02/2016 12:31:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'user1');
Insert into PMS2020.STRINGLIST
   (ID, STRINGID, STRING, STRING_START, STRING_END, 
    CREATE_DATE, CREATED_BY, EXPIRE_DATE, EXPIRED_BY)
 Values
   (2, 1, 'string1', 0.1, 5, 
    TO_DATE('04/02/2016 12:31:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'user1', TO_DATE('02/02/2016 12:31:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'user1');
Insert into PMS2020.STRINGLIST
   (ID, STRINGID, STRING, STRING_START, STRING_END, 
    CREATE_DATE, CREATED_BY, EXPIRE_DATE, EXPIRED_BY)
 Values
   (3, 1, 'string1', 0.12, 5.2, 
    TO_DATE('04/02/2016 12:31:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'user1', TO_DATE('04/02/2018 12:31:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'user1');
Insert into PMS2020.STRINGLIST
   (ID, STRINGID, STRING, STRING_START, STRING_END, 
    CREATE_DATE, CREATED_BY, EXPIRE_DATE, EXPIRED_BY)
 Values
   (4, 1, 'string1', 0.5, 6, 
    TO_DATE('04/02/2018 12:32:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'user1', TO_DATE('04/02/2019 12:32:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'user1');
Insert into PMS2020.STRINGLIST
   (ID, STRINGID, STRING, STRING_START, STRING_END, 
    CREATE_DATE, CREATED_BY)
 Values
   (5, 1, 'string1', 0.75, 6.5, 
    TO_DATE('04/02/2019 12:32:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'user1');
COMMIT;
```

[image: String List Table]

It is easy to get the current string size:

```
select *
from stringlist
where stringid = 1
and expiry_date is null;
```

What will the query look like to get the latest string size for :

2015  0.1 - 5

2016  0.12 - 5.2

2017  0.12 - 5.2 (not changes was done in 2017, so 2016 value is still valid)

2018  0.5 - 6

2019  0.75 - 6.5

The user will just need to select the type of string and the year.
And the size must be displayed on a report for the selected year.

A very simple way will be to just add a string_year. So there will be a record for each string for each year. But that will give you duplication for 2016 and 2017, because nothing changed in 2017.

This is obviously a very simplistic explanation of the system. The "strings" also have a lot of different attributes etc. But that is not important for this question.

How will you handle something like this? What will your db design be?

Comment: Are you asking for a better DB design than the one you present?

Comment: Better db design or how would a select statement work? That is not to complicated? Meaning this is just a simple example. Real system is complex with a lot of tables and dependencies.Report queries are already complex with joins etc.

Comment: If the EXPIRE_DATE is always going to be the same as the next row's START_DATE, I'd just eliminate the EXPIRE_DATE and EXPIRED_BY columns.  Otherwise, your table looks fine.

Comment: Oh, in row 2 of your data, the expire date comes before the start date.  Is that a typo, or is that possible with your real-world data?

Comment: Typo. Sorry. Not possible in real world data

Comment: How will my select query look like if I want the valid info for 2017?

Comment: Can you correct your data then? From the output I guess row 2 create date (and row 1 end date) is supposed to be 2015-04-02 instead of 2016? Also are you trying to see the result for all years at once or for a single year?

Comment: Do some research on temporal databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a single year at a time you could do:

```
select max(string_start) keep (dense_rank last order by create_date) as string_start,
       max(string_end)   keep (dense_rank last order by create_date) as string_end
from stringlist
where create_date < last_day(to_date(to_char(2017), 'YYYY')) + 1;

STRING_START STRING_END
------------ ----------
         .12        5.2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1df71c/1)

or:

```
select string_start, string_end
from (
  select string_start, string_end, row_number() over (order by create_date desc) as rn
  from stringlist
  where create_date < last_day(to_date(to_char(2017), 'YYYY')) + 1
)
where rn = 1;

STRING_START STRING_END
------------ ----------
         .12        5.2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1df71c/2)

In both cases you're excluding all data before the start of the following year, and then finding the values for the row that's left with the latest create date.

Answer (score 0):

The following query can be used to see all string data over the years a string is active:

```sql
WITH string_years (stringid, report_year) AS
(
  SELECT s.stringid, y.y
  FROM (SELECT sl.stringid,
               EXTRACT(YEAR FROM min(create_date)) AS MIN_YEAR,
               EXTRACT(YEAR FROM max(create_date)) AS MAX_YEAR
        FROM stringlist sl
        GROUP BY sl.stringid) s
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN_YEAR+LEVEL-1 AS Y
              FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM min(create_date)) AS MIN_YEAR,
                           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM max(create_date)) AS MAX_YEAR
                    FROM stringlist) s
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (s.max_year-s.min_year)+1) y ON y.y BETWEEN s.min_year AND s.max_year
)
SELECT sy.stringid, sy.report_year, 
       NVL(i.first_change, LAG(i.first_change) OVER (PARTITION BY sy.stringid ORDER BY sy.report_year)) AS START_INFO,
       NVL(i.last_change, LAG(i.last_change) OVER(PARTITION BY sy.stringid ORDER BY sy.report_year)) AS END_INFO
FROM string_years sy
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sl.stringid, 
                  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sl.create_date) AS REPORT_YEAR, 
                  MAX(sl.string_start) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sl.create_date) AS FIRST_CHANGE,
                  MAX(sl.string_end) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sl.create_date) AS LAST_CHANGE
            FROM stringlist sl
            GROUP BY sl.stringid, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sl.create_date)) i ON sy.stringid = i.stringid AND sy.report_year = i.report_year
```

Accompanying [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f473/22/0)

The string_years CTE lists our all years a string is active, even if it has no events.  Active years are all years between the first and last event for a string.  Then we left join that to our yearly extract grouping the aggregate functions by STRINGID and YEAR.  Finally if a row is null, we use the LAG function to grab the value from the previous year.

If you are going to limit this query to a specific string or type of string, it might not hurt to create another CTE prior to the `STRING_YEARS` one to use in place of stringlist throughout the rest of the query.